# Updating MYSQL Database fail, why?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$serverid = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM serveripank");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($serverid)) {
  require_once('../getdata/cs-getdata.php');
  $result = $cstrike->getData();
  $SNAME = $result['cstrike']['ServerVars']['servername']; //Server name
  $SMAP = $result['cstrike']['ServerVars']['mapname']; //Map name
  $SCP = $result['cstrike']['ServerVars']['currentplayers']; //Server Current Players
  $SMP = $result['cstrike']['ServerVars']['maxplayers']; //Server Max Players
  // Servers name MAX 25 letters & Map
  $SNAME = substr($SNAME, 0, 25);
  $SMAP = substr($SMAP, 0, 20);

  $id = $row['id'];
  mysql_query("UPDATE serveripank SET players = '$SCP' WHERE id = '$id'");
  mysql_query("UPDATE serveripank SET maxplayers = '$SMP' WHERE id = '$id'");
  mysql_query("UPDATE serveripank SET map = '$SMAP' WHERE id = '$id'");
  mysql_query("UPDATE serveripank SET srname = '$SNAME' WHERE id = '$id'");
}
```

Im using this script http://dev.ush-network.de/2010/02/02/gathering-counter-strike-data-using-php-sockets/comment-page-1/#comment-22 in `require_once('../getdata/cs-getdata.php');`

When i go to the link to update my MYSQL database, it doesnt display any errors but in database the rows are empty.

This is in my cs-getdata.php file @ the bottom, so it could update all the servers with the right values... ( Dont know how to explain better )

`list($ip, $port) = explode(":", "row['ip']");
$cstrike = new cstrike_statistics();
$cstrike->setHostname('$ip');
$cstrike->setPort($port);`

My problem is that it doesnt get the server info / and it puts empty values to the database.

Comment: Try outputting the queries, and be sure to do a `echo mysql_error();` to see any errors

Comment: outputting ? sorry im bad in english and i didnt quite understand that .. 
I did the mysql_error echo, didnt show any errors.

Comment: @Kristjan I mean, output the queries using `echo` (`echo "UPDATE...."`) and see what they contain.

Comment: http://www.mg.rps.ee/serveripank/scripts/refreshdata2.php

I have about 50 servers what need to be updated, and $SNAME, $SMAP etc... dont contain anything... Why is that so ?

Comment: @Kristjan but then the problem is not the queries, but `cstrike->getData()`, isn't it?

Comment: Try `print_r($result);` after the `getData()` to see whether any data is fetched at all

Comment: No data is being fetched, but i did everything so it should ? I mean i did the require thing after the mysql_fetch_array, and then it required the cs-getdata.php, at the last lines there are "row['ip']" etc... It should work ... :S

Comment: @Kristjan hmmm, the problem is probably in the `cs-getdata.php` part of the code

Comment: How ? I provided the code in the main post that i made, everything else in that code is correct.

Comment: list($ip, $port) = explode(":", "row['ip']");
$cstrike = new cstrike_statistics();
$cstrike->setHostname('$ip');
$cstrike->setPort($port);

Something in here should be wrong...

Answer (score -1):

Oh my god, why didnt anyone notice my silly mistake?

```
list($ip, $port) = explode(":", "row['ip']"); 
$cstrike = new cstrike_statistics(); 
$cstrike->setHostname('$ip'); 
$cstrike->setPort($port);
```

should be

```
list($ip, $port) = explode(":", "$row['ip']"); 
$cstrike = new cstrike_statistics(); 
$cstrike->setHostname('$ip'); 
$cstrike->setPort($port);
```

Mistake was: `$row['ip']`

Comment: it should be `$cstrike->setHostname($ip);` without single quote

Comment: Still doesnt add anything to the database.

Comment: Because it's your job. not anyone's else

Comment: Yeah, but beginners like me need help with these stuff. OK?